# Store data from while to array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

I have a static array like this.

```
$row = array($aRow['colum_name_1'],$aRow['colum_name_2'],$aRow['colum_name_3']);
```

I want store my data using while loop in php for dynamic column in array

This is my code:

```
while ($aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
$data = "";
$data_cus_dt1 = mysqli_query($con,"select column_name from custom_table_column");
            while($my_cus_dt=mysqli_fetch_object($data_cus_dt1))
            {
                $mydata = $my_cus_dt->column_name; 
                $data  .= $aRow[$mydata].",";
            }   
   $row = array($data);
}
```

I want to result dynamic column, like static array.

```
$row = array($aRow['colum_name_1'],$aRow['colum_name_2'],$aRow['colum_name_3']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no point using `$data` variable in your code, that too as a string. You can directly use the `$row` array(initially empty) in the inner `while()` loop to get the resultant array.

```
$row = array();
while ($aRow = $rResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $data_cus_dt1 = mysqli_query($con,"select column_name from custom_table_column");
    while($my_cus_dt=mysqli_fetch_object($data_cus_dt1)){
        $row[] = $aRow[$my_cus_dt->column_name]; 
    }   
}
```